# How to force install a windows optional feature which was completely deleted and is absent from the Dism /online /Get-Features?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11, wsl2, dism

The original Windows 11 installer ISO was modified to work in a constrained resources settings and thus had completely removed the trace of most of the Windows' components, packages, or features to minimize the final installed size. And this modified ISO was used to install on the current system. So that even running `Dism /online /Get-Features` won't list the feature.

**Mounting the original (unmodified) official full Windows 11 ISO image:**

```
PS C:\> Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:E:\Sources\install.wim /Index:7 /MountDir:C:\test\offline /Readonly

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.22621.1

Mounting image
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.
```

**The original ISO has the feature:**

```
PS C:\> Dism /Image:C:\test\offline /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.22621.1

Image Version: 10.0.22621.525

Feature Information:

Feature Name : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
Display Name : Windows Subsystem for Linux
Description : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows.
Restart Required : Possible
State : Disabled

Custom Properties:

ServerComponent\Description : Provides services and environments for running native user-mode Linux shells and tools on Windows.
ServerComponent\DisplayName : Windows Subsystem for Linux
ServerComponent\Id : 1033
ServerComponent\Type : Feature
ServerComponent\UniqueName : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
ServerComponent\Deploys\Update\Name : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

The operation completed successfully.
```

**The feature was completed deleted (on the modified ISO installer), so on the installed windows, feature is not recognized:**

```
PS C:\> Dism /Online /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.22621.1

Image Version: 10.0.22621.1245


Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and try the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

**It fails to install the feature as it is not recognized (although present on the /Source) :**

```
PS C:\> Dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /Source:C:\test\offline\Windows\WinSxS\ /All /LimitAccess

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.22621.1

Image Version: 10.0.22621.1245


Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and try the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

DISM was used, but the solution doesn't have to use DISM. Also, if standalone installers exist for each optional feature that would be a valid solution.
Now, how to enable such feature(s) (and the dependencies) without performing the full OS installation?

**Log file ( C:\Windows\Logs\Dism\dism.log ) only for the last command:**

```
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   PID=20420 TID=20424 Scratch directory set to 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\'. - CDISMManager::put_ScratchDir
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   PID=20420 TID=20424 DismCore.dll version: 10.0.22621.1 - CDISMManager::FinalConstruct
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   PID=20420 TID=20424 Successfully loaded the ImageSession at "C:\Windows\system32\Dism" - CDISMManager::LoadLocalImageSession
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=20420 TID=20424 Found and Initialized the DISM Logger. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_InitializeLogger
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=20420 TID=20424 Successfully created the local image session and provider store. - CDISMManager::CreateLocalImageSession
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Starting Dism.exe session ----->
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Host machine information: OS Version=10.0.22621, Running architecture=amd64, Number of processors=2
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Dism.exe version: 10.0.22621.1
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Executing command line: "C:\Windows\system32\Dism.exe" /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /Source:C:\test\offline\Windows\WinSxS\ /All /LimitAccess
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=20420 TID=20424 physical location path: C:\ - CDISMManager::CreateImageSession
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=20420 TID=20424 Event name for current DISM session is Global\{3215538E-EA92-474F-A021-31BC279C7964} - CDISMManager::CheckSessionAndLock
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=20420 TID=20424 Create session event 0x248 for current DISM session and event name is Global\{3215538E-EA92-474F-A021-31BC279C7964}  - CDISMManager::CheckSessionAndLock
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=20420 TID=20424 Copying DISM from "C:\Windows\System32\Dism" - CDISMManager::CreateImageSessionFromLocation
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=20420 TID=20424 No Sandbox was created, DISM running in-place. - CDISMManager::CreateImageSessionFromLocation
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=20420 TID=20424 Successfully loaded the ImageSession at "C:\Windows\System32\Dism" - CDISMManager::LoadRemoteImageSession
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Image Session: PID=20448 TID=20468 Instantiating the Provider Store. - CDISMImageSession::get_ProviderStore
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM OS Provider: PID=20448 TID=20468 Defaulting SystemPath to C:\ - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM OS Provider: PID=20448 TID=20468 Defaulting Windows folder to C:\Windows - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=20448 TID=20468 Attempting to initialize the logger from the Image Session. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=20448 TID=20468 Found and Initialized the DISM Logger. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_InitializeLogger
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=20420 TID=20424 Image session successfully loaded from location: C:\Windows\System32\Dism - CDISMManager::CreateImageSession
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Target image information: OS Version=10.0.22621.1245, Image architecture=amd64
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session version: 10.0.22621.1
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=20448 TID=20468 Current image session is [ONLINE] - CTransmogManager::GetMode
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=20448 TID=20468 Audit Mode: [No] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=20448 TID=20468 GetProductType: ProductType = [WinNT] - CTransmogManager::GetProductType
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=20448 TID=20468 Product Type: [WinNT] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Transmog Provider: PID=20448 TID=20468 Product Type ServerNT : [No] - CTransmogManager::Initialize
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  CSI    00000001 Shim considered [l:126]'\??\C:\Windows\Servicing\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.1245_none_e95e4cae42cdfd26\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  CSI    00000002 Shim considered [l:123]'\??\C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.1245_none_e95e4cae42cdfd26\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_SUCCESS
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Driver Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Further logs for driver related operations can be found in the target operating system at %WINDIR%\inf\setupapi.offline.log - CDriverManager::Initialize
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Finished initializing the CbsConUI Handler. - CCbsConUIHandler::Initialize
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 CBS is being initialized for online use. More information about CBS actions can be located at: %windir%\logs\CBS\CBS.log - CDISMPackageManager::Initialize
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Loaded servicing stack for online use. - CDISMPackageManager::CreateCbsSession
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  CSI    00000001 Shim considered [l:126]'\??\C:\Windows\Servicing\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.1245_none_e95e4cae42cdfd26\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  CSI    00000002 Shim considered [l:123]'\??\C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.22621.1245_none_e95e4cae42cdfd26\wcp.dll' : got STATUS_SUCCESS
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Processing the top level command token(enable-feature). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Encountered the option "featurename" with value "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Encountered an unknown option "featurename" with value "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Encountered the option "source" with value "C:\test\offline\Windows\WinSxS\" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Encountered an unknown option "source" with value "C:\test\offline\Windows\WinSxS\" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetPackagesFromCommandLine
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Failed to get the Update through CBS. - CDISMPackage::Internal_OpenFeature(hr:0x800f080c)
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Failed to get the underlying CBS Feature - CDISMPackage::OpenFeature(hr:0x800f080c)
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 Feature name Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux is unknown. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetFeaturesFromCommandLine(hr:0x800f080c)
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Unknown features were specified on the command-line. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetFeaturesFromCommandLine(hr:0x800f080c)
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Failed to get the Feature List from the command line. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange(hr:0x800f080c)
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Failed while processing command enable-feature. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f080c)
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=20448 TID=20468 Finalizing CBS core. - CDISMPackageManager::Finalize
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=20420 TID=20424 Closing session event handle 0x248 - CDISMManager::CleanupImageSessionEntry
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
2023-02-07 02:52:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE:
```

Comment: Using the ISO is the only method, I suppose if you’re using 22H2 you could install directly from the Windows Store, there is no way to add the feature back to WinSxS without reinstalling Windows. Why can’t you use an unmodified ISO to install these features? You ran into the problem with customizing the ISO and removing features to reduce the size of your Windows installation. I am confused by what your problem is, it appears mounting the ISO, is a workable solution

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, the question should be crystal clear. Modified ISO is used for the windows OS installation and original full (unmodified official ISO) is being used for DISM to try to install the feature. The question is to get the feature working without doing full re-installation.

Comment: Clear the `C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log` then run the last command and provide us the log.

Comment: @Ramhound Okay. I have appended the contents of the dism.log for the last command, at the end of the question.

Comment: @Ramhound As mentioned on the question, please note that this is not a normal installation of windows. It is an extremely minified installation to work on a resource constrained environment. So, guessing, possibly first some configuration or registry settings need to be added so that first it can recognize the feature or somehow first the command: `Dism /Online /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` should produce desired output before the `Enable-Feature` can work. Or, as I am not an expert in this, maybe the command is not in proper syntax.

Comment: It shouldn’t matter if you provided a source for the feature

Comment: @Ramhound Any iideas on possible solutions without reinstalling from official iso?

Comment: You can either install from the ISO itself but failing that reinstalling Windows likely is your only solution.  DISM (or the appropriate PowerShell command) is the only other way to install features, PowerShell just calls DISM, so if one fails the other will fail also. Your guess about the registry key isn't on the mark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142694/discussion-between-user3330840-and-ramhound).